# VSCode typescript does not auto import from shortest path

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I have the following `paths` property in my `tsconfig.json` file (typescript react project):

```
        "paths": {
          "@src/*": ["src/*"],
          "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
          "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
          "@hooks/*": ["src/hooks/*"]
        }
```

I want the auto import to use the shortest path possible. The problem is that auto import automatically uses `src` as the parent path instead of the inner paths.

[Example auto import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgyo7.png)

In the example above, I want `useLoading` to be imported from `@hooks/LoadingContext` instead of `@src/hooks/LoadingContext`

I don't wanna remove the `@src/*` mapping if possible.

I've looked in this site and in the tsconfig and VSCode docs and haven't seen anything pertaining to it. Not even sure which config I should change to be honest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the paths order so it goes like this:

```
"paths": {
  "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
  "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
  "@hooks/*": ["src/hooks/*"],
  "@src/*": ["src/*"]
}
```

The longest path should be the latest one.

Comment: This is the correct solution! Somehow I couldn't find anything in the official docs for this. I also already tried this before but didn't refresh the editor. I just refreshed after doing this and now it imports properly. Thanks!